# Creating a new column based on Calendar function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a **data frame**:

```
    Year     Month    Week_of_month Day_of_week 
0     2018      1         2             1         
1     2018      1         1             2         
2     2018      1         2             2          
3     2018      1         1             3          
4     2018      1         2             3          
5     2018      1         1             4          
6     2018      1         2             4          
7     2018      1         1             5         
8     2018      1         2             5         
9     2018      1         1             6          
10    2018      1         2             6       
11    2018      1         1             7
```

Which contains:

> - Day of week (1 to 7 -> Sunday until Saturday)
> - Week of the month (1 until 6 - One month has a maximum of 6 weeks)

I would like to get the corresponding day based on those 4 information:

So, for example, to get the `30th of december of 2018`, I did this:

[image]

I used this **function**:

```
calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)
calendar.monthcalendar(2018,12)

    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
     [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
     [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
     [30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

calendar.monthcalendar(2018,12)[5][1]
31
```

The point is:
How do I use this function to get each day in each row of my **dataframe** ?.

I tried this:

```
df['Day'] = calendar.monthcalendar(df.Year, df.Month)[df.Week_of_month][df.Day_of_week]
```

However, I got an **error**:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df['Day'] = df.apply(lambda x: calendar.monthcalendar(x.Year, x.Month)[x.Week_of_month-1][x.Day_of_week-1], axis=1)
```

The output:

[image]

Hope this helps.